# Why do we use $z$ for representing complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation, math-history

Why do we use $z$ for representing complex number? Is there any specific reason? or just tradition

Comment: We use $x$ for the $x$-axis, $y$ for the imaginary (or second axis), and the next letter is $z$.

Comment: Good question! I've always assumed it was just the next "unknown" letter available after you've written $x+iy$ with real $x,y$, but that's just speculation.

Comment: Also, $w$ is used just as often for $x+iy$

Comment: Nothing specific... [$x,y,z$](http://jeff560.tripod.com/variables.html) were introduced by Descartes to refer to *variables*. Gauss used $a+bi$ for complex numbers.

Comment: It certainly might be interesting to trace back the literature of complex analysis to see when $z$ became a standard. In my copy of Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" (first published in 1953, my copy is the 1976 revision), it's already $z$ with $w$ used also in order to have separate dependent and independent variables in expressions like $w=f(z)$.

Comment: [Euler](http://eulerarchive.maa.org//tour/tour_08.html) used it in 1777.

Comment: Why is why called why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply convention and we could denote them any way we want but there is a motivation one might give to do this, which I'd argue is the complex plane.

We tend to express coordinates with $x$ and $y$ (again, a convention but a quite common one) and a complex number $z$ can be written as a sum of its real part and imaginary part in the following way:
$$z=x+iy.$$

This means a complex number in a certain sense has an $x$ and a $y$ coordinate representation where you can place them in a Cartesian coordinate system with one axis being $x$ and one being $y$. I would argue it's natural notation to choose $z$ as the third letter in such a tupel but as said this all boils down to conventions being based on other conventions.

For information on this, if you don't already know, it might be worth looking at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we do not always denote a complex number by $z=x+iy$. In the theory of Dirichlet series people prefer 
$$
s=\sigma+it,
$$
for example for the Riemann zeta function
$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}, 
$$
for $\sigma>1$.

Comment: It is because the Laplace/Mellin transform uses the letter $s$ (Dirichlet series are Mellin transforms)